# Android: Login with a google account (using Android Query)

Tags: android, android-query

I'm using android query on my android mobile app.
It is very simple to log in with Facebook:

```
String appid = "7315348484584";
String permisions = "email";

FacebookHandle handle = new FacebookHandle(this, appid, permisions);

String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
aq.auth(handle).ajax(url, JSONObject.class, this, "bfCallback");
```

In callback i get user profile info(name, email, gender, etc.)

```
public void bfCallback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status)
```

How can I do the same thing for a google account?

So! I need to get User's Google Account info: fname, lname, email, gender. How can I do this - **not using** `google play service`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AQuery has a `GoogleHandle` class which handles authentication to a number of Google services such as Picasa, Spreadsheets, Youtube, Analytics, Blogger, Calendar, Contacts, and Maps as per the [Supported Google Services table](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/Authentication#Supported_Google_Service).

However, other services, such as Google Account information, is **not** available via AQuery.